# Is it possible to get the last occurrence of a newline in a text node with XPath 1.0?

Tags: xpath

I think the answer is "no" but I'll ask anyway. Can you find the last occurrence of a newline in text node using XPath 1.0?

E.g. Given the following XML I want to find the last newline (immediately after "second") in order to get the text "third".

```
<element> first
  second
  third </element>
```

If I knew the position of the last newline it would be trivial to get the text after it. I don't actually want to return the value, just test against it.

As far as I can tell XPath 1.0 doesn't have any of:

- reverse text functions
- loops
- character axis/node
- regex
- string split

Any of the above would be enough to solve this problem!

Comment: XPath 1.0 doesn't have this power, but in case you could use XSLT (even 1.0), this can be done.

Comment: @DimitreNovatchev I'm using the DOMXPath class in PHP. Does your comment still apply?

Comment: CJ Dennis, I don't know PHP -- probably you can just get the complete text node and find the text in the last line using PHP. I thought that you may be using XSLT together with XPath -- which is often the case, because XSLT is a language, especially designed for processing XML documents

Answer (score 2):

> Can you find the last occurrence of a newline in text node using XPath 1.0?

No. XPath generally has not been designed to do string processing.

Of course in XPath 2.0 you can do it by tokenizing the input into sequence and then getting the last element from that sequence. But strictly speaking that does not qualify as text processing, it's sequence handling. In other words, it won't actually give you the position of that last newline character either.

with XPath 1.0 you will have to do this bit of work in the host language.